# Printing for Safari with window.print()

Tags: printing, safari, mobile-safari, vuejs3

I am trying to print one of my vue-routes. Therefore vue-html-to-paper is not working properly with Vue3. Using print.js, it was not possible somehow to include a local css-file.

I did the following basic css for printing then:

```
// global printing
@media print {
  @page {
    size: A4;
  }

  // hide buttons and non-content
  button,
  aside {
    display: none !important;
  }

  // somehow there are no line-break, so border content
  div {
    max-width: 100vw;
  }

  // footer
  body::after {
    content: url("../assets/printfooter.png");

    // center
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

This works smooth and simple as I expect on

- Firefox 85.0 (64-bit)
- Chrome 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- even on my cell using Chrome 88.0.4324.152

Trying to print on Safari does not work.

- on desktop version 14.0.2 half the content gets out of bounds.
- on mobile iPhone 14.4. it just uses half screen.

Any hint what secret I have to do to satisfy Apple or what I can improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem was the @page rule, which is not supported my Safari. See more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@page

I end up creating the pdf with pdfkit server side.